# Whats the use of memcached when time needs to be spend over wire accessing data over network?

Tags: memcached

Network is far more expensive then disk, and disk is more expensive them memory.
But if we access 'memcache-D' over network, then does not the time spent over network dwarf, the benefit of accessing data from memory?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one server, one piece of data and the luxury to choose where to have this (disk, memory, server-over-network), then sure, you're on to something. But reality isn't that clean most of the time.

Where did the data come from? Maybe a couple of servers are feeding very calculation-entensive data to your server-over-network and the fact you don't need to do those calculations saves you tons of time.
Maybe you have 10 servers needing the same information, so the overhead of the network is a good trade-off against the needed memory.

There are all kinds of reasons you want this, but the first step would be to directly get it from source. Then you might want to have it in memory. Then maybe a caching system on the same server as your application, then maybe a shared machine, a cluster, etc. Expand-as-needed.